# My account is not accepting any more questions

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

I have read other questions that have similar problems and I am not able to see if this is a permanent ban or something but the question that i have asked is really DEBATABLE its general yes but also its understanding of techinical jargon, my account over is at stackoverflow same name as this account, pls assist

if any moderator seeing this i have had a same issue last time and it was automatic system ban and later re-activated it.

Comment: See [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Comment: @hims056 I DID as i mentioned in my first line itself!! but donot understand wether it is permanent or temporary or a system autokicked in...pls read...tks

Comment: Then read the content of that question and its first answer. It gives you the answer. It is permanent if YOU don't do anything about it. This ban is automatic. Nobody will manually lift your ban. All the information is contained within that question and its answer.

Comment: @Bart I also mentioned my question is indeed DEBATABLE in my above question here in CAPS, so debatable means can some one tell me how its wrong to ask a technical jargon that a user dont really understand?

Comment: What question which you have asked is really debatable? You might want to clarify because I have no clue what you're getting at. If you're trying to say that you have been banned because of one question, then I can assure you that is not the case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480464/can-this-be-an-abstract

Comment: Y AM I STILL GETTING DOWN VOTES FOR SUCH A CLEAR EXPLANATION????

Comment: I'm sorry, but that question is not a question you have. It's your homework. You can't seriously tell me that the question you ask yourself is *"Should the class Property be implemented as an abstract class? Use not more than 5 sentences to justify your answer"* ... I never limit myself to 5 sentences when asking myself a question... So you ask us to answer your homework question for you in a way that will most likely only ever be useful to you. It's too localized as a result.

Comment: @Bart i was merely stating what i have in the question that was given to me and yes it indeed was a homework but i was not enforcing anyone to limit to fivequestions in there answers but just a explanation on abstract as you see I also mentioned that explain with code and did not say to just give me answers.

Comment: @Bart someone edited the question what can i do about it?

Comment: In any case, your ban is not about this single question (which in my opinion got rightfully closed). Your ban is most likely the result of the overall quality of your questions. That it happened after asking that particular question is a coincidence at best.

Comment: The edits are not problematic. Don't do anything about them. They are just fine. You might actually want to take note of them to ask better questions from the start.

Comment: @JackyBoi: on Meta, downvotes are not the same as on Stack Overflow proper. It often means they disagree with your statements.

Comment: well in that case, so the only option I have is? I am not sure how to proceed from here forth.

Comment: Once again, read the answer of the duplicate question. It contains all the information including what you can do. And besides that Matt has given you some pointers in his answer below as well.

Comment: Let me explain again. So this is not a permanent ban right?

Comment: Not if you do all that is indicated within the answer to get out of your ban. This is about what you will do. The ban is automatic. If you don't do anything, then the ban will be permanent. Nobody will ever manually lift your ban. There is no time-limit to the ban. This is about you, your actions and your positive contributions. Really, read the answer. All the information is there. We're only repeating content here.

Comment: As for your *"I DID as i mentioned in my first line itself!!"*: no, you did not. How are readers to guess that *"I have read other questions"* refers to that specific question? Also, the fact that you're asking *"So this is not a permanent ban right?"* just tells me you did not read that post well enough.

Comment: @JackyBoi isn't this frustrating? asking a question and get hammered with down votes? I posted about this and also got hammered. Then the consequence of that is question banned.

Comment: @Jackie ya.. now a days I just use it if it is ABSOLUTELY necessary

Answer (score 2):

Your average votes/question isn't too bad... are you sure you haven't been deleting questions with negative votes? (Those are still taken into account.)

Answers are also taken into account (I think), so post some decent answers, attract some upvotes, and tip the scales.

You can also edit your low-voted-questions to improve them, which'll bump them to the top page and hopefully give you some upvotes as well.

Also, if all your questions are posted in the same style as this one, you need to learn how to format and spell-check your posts. [/o]

Comment: Tks for the useful comments Matt, perhaps its time i did something about it then.. pls see my questions at stackoverflow and upvote if anyof them are really helpful to you tks.. so much!

Comment: Your comment is already indicative of the general quality. Please say "Thanks", "I" instead of "i", "please" instead of "pls", etc. They are details, but important details nonetheless

Comment: @JackyBoi - It should be pointed out that Matt can only see your non-deleted questions. You have nine questions that have been deleted, five of which were significantly downvoted. Several of these questions were deleted by you, which weighs against you in the question quality heuristics. If you'd like, I could undelete those and let you clean them up.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks, Brad really appreciate that. But by cleaning them up and rather than getting downvoted, that is IF those questions get downvoted wont that be even worse than now? Please explain as I am really confused and helpless. By the way those questions I deleted them are really not very good questions which I presonally felt after posting them, but your expert advice is much welcome.

Comment: @CDR you made a totally useless and minor edit to a very old post. Please do not do it again, it just create noise in the homepage.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard  - okay, sorry, good to know.